# AngularJS :Error: $compile:tpload Error Loading Template during load the page?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

[image]

I have to perform the routing functionality in Angularjs. I got an error during load of the page as well as click on the tabs .How to fix this error?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <p><a href="#/!">Main</a></p>
  <a href="#!red">Red</a>
  <a href="#!green">Green</a>
  <a href="#!blue">Blue</a>

  <div ng-view></div>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
        app.config(function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider
            .when("/", {
                templateUrl : "main.html"
            })
            .when("/red", {
                templateUrl : "red.html"
            })
            .when("/green", {
                templateUrl : "green.html"
            })
            .when("/blue", {
                templateUrl : "blue.html"
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

?

Comment: This error occurs when $compile attempts to fetch a template from some URL, and the request fails.

To resolve this error, ensure that the URL of the template is spelled correctly and resolves to correct absolute URL.

Comment: sir spelling is properly but its'not working.

Answer (score 1):

You have to include the corresponding HTML Files `main.html`, `red.html`,`green.html` and  `blue.html` in the same directory as your index file.

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl : "main.html"
    })
    .when("/red", {
        templateUrl : "red.html"
    })
    .when("/green", {
        templateUrl : "green.html"
    })
    .when("/blue", {
        templateUrl : "blue.html"
    });
});
```

**Working Plunker**: https://plnkr.co/edit/NqvLYxo66Yj2U7Ytw1DX?p=preview

Comment: Which is your main html? home.html?

Comment: main.html is my home page is main.html?

Comment: See main.html is a view, rename the main.html as index.html and create a partial called main.html. Check my plunker to understand

Comment: sir i have rename the main.html as index.html now this time view will be change but i got main  error  Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, ?

Comment: Now how many templates you have got and are all of them residing in the same directory?

Comment: sir totally 4 templates including the  index.html file.yes it it in same directory?

Comment: It should be 5- red,green,blue,main,index .Check my plunker and see the routing. See your routing, you have specified main.html to be loaded when url is "/" but you have not defined it in your directory

Comment: Copy paste my code and see if it is working. And now how many templates do you have and what are their routing?

Comment: Sir I pasted your code and again its not working and  i have totally 5 templates included?

Comment: your code might be having some problem because it is working in the plunker

Comment: Ok sir I will check my code.sir it is possible with the install http server or not ?

Comment: What is the url on your browser when you load the page? What http server are you talking about?

Comment: this URL will be generated: file:///C:/Users/Dell-pc/Desktop/routing/index.html#!/

Comment: Is anything rendering on that url?

Comment: means sir, i don't undestand ?